# Using a GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN for PRs

Tags: composer-php, travis-ci, github-api

Using a `GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN`, one can use Travis to go past the API rate limit on `composer install`. However, this token is linked to the account of the owner of the repository, and cannot be used for P.R. made on this repo. Is there anyway to go past this limit for P.R.? I thought of two solutions:

1. Have Travis use the token of the person that makes the P.R.
2. Have Travis use the token of the repo owner if he somehow "trusts" the person that makes the P.R. (dunno how the trust relationship should be defined though.

Needless to say, I think 1. is best.

[Example of failing build](https://travis-ci.org/sonata-project/SonataAdminSearchBundle/builds/68165528)

Comment: Disagree for option 2. It's too dangerous, anybody can make a PR with a smilpe `echo $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN` inside Travis script to get the concerned key.

Comment: That's why the guy who makes the P.R. should be somehow "trusted" (but explicitely, for instance by following him on github or sth like that)

Comment: but I guess that would be **very** cumbersome

Comment: What is the problem you want to get solved? I'd say that because Travis CI is closely tied to Github, and because you'd setup an account at Travis with Oauth authorization on Github, Travis should be able to use that token to run tests. I'd consider this the task of this infrastructure to provide an environment that is able to do what it's supposed to do - if it explicitly supports PHP and Composer, it should be able to also support downloading lots of dependencies without the need to deal with authentication. Did you run into problems? You would be the first to have them that I hear of.

Comment: Travis should not be able to use **my** token to run other people's code (the one in their P.R.s), agreed ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically the solution to this particular problem was : do not cache 
the vendor directory, as the composer cache already has most of the information in this directory. The presence of vendors can prevent composer to try alternative download methods, making failure of a method problematic.

To quote [Stof](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4147#issuecomment-115258930) :

> the issue is that you are not only persisting the composer cache between builds, but also the vendor folder itself. In case of updating an existing installed package, composer will indeed not fallback to a different installation method (which would require switching to a remove/install process rather than an update process btw). It tries only the existing method.
>   I suggest that you only persist the cache between builds, not the vendor folder (the API rate limit is only impacted for cache misses anyway).
>
> And if you don't have a token for PR coming from forks, it is not a big issues IMO: they will hit the cache most of the time once it is populated by branch builds